# Finding nodes with enough unique ancestors

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, directed-acyclic-graph

Given a DAG $G = (V, E)$, let $T \subseteq V$ be a set of nodes of $V$ that is computed via the following process. Assuming the nodes of $G$ are sorted in topological order, $v_1, \dots, v_n$. We process the nodes in this topological order. Suppose we are processing vertex $v_i$ in the order. Let $r(v_i)$ be the set of ancestors of $v_i$. We add $v_i$ and all ancestors of $v_i$ into $T$ if and only if the number of ancestors of $v_i$ (including $v_i$ itself) that are not in $T$ is at least $\frac{|r(v_i)| + 1}{f}$ where $f$ is some constant $f > 1$ provided as part of the input. If a vertex is added to $T$, then all its ancestors are also added into $T$. Any algorithm that computes $T$ must satisfy the following invariant: any vertex $v_i$ added into $T$ must have at least $\frac{|r(v_i)| + 1}{f}$ of its ancestors (including itself) not in $T$ when it was added, and any vertex $v_i$ not added into $T$ must have $< \frac{|r(v_i)| + 1}{f}$ of its ancestors (including itself) not in $T$.

**Problem:** Provide an algorithm that runs in $\tilde{O}(m + n)$ time (meaning ignoring polylogarithmic factors) that provides a valid set $T$ given an input graph $G = (V, E)$ and the processing order of the vertices is the toposort order. Approximation (meaning constant error on the $\frac{r(v_i)+1}{f}$ condition) and Las Vegas algorithms are welcome also. You may preprocess the graph but the preprocessing time must also be $\tilde{O}(m + n)$.

**Trivial Solution in More Time** We can do this trivially in $O(nm)$ time. For each $v_i$, we find via BFS its set of ancestors and check whether each one is in $T$. From this we can compute the exact fraction that is not in $T$ and either put $v_i$ and $r(v_i)$ in $T$ or not.

**Example Problem:** Suppose you have the following trivial DAG (below) and $f= 2$.

> a -> b -> c

Then, $T = \{a, b\}$. $a$ is processed first and $T = \emptyset$ at first so $a$ is added into $T$. Then, $b$ is processed after $a$ and is added to $T$ since $1/2$ of the vertices in $\{a, b\}$ are not in $T$. Finally, $c$ is processed and not added to $T$ since it has at most $1/3$ of the vertices in $\{a, b, c\}$ are not in $T$. Note that in this example, a trivial $O(n)$ algorithm for any line is to keep a counter $c$ of the *index* of the last element added to $T$ (since adding the element at $c$ also means adding all its ancestors) and add the $i$-th element of the line to $T$ if $\frac{i-c}{i} \geq \frac{1}{f}$. However, this problem is much less trivial for general graphs.

Has anyone seen a problem similar to this in the literature or algorithms which solve similar problems?

Comment: It would be enough to compute $|r(v_i)|$ and the number of ancestors of $v_i$ in $T$ for each node as you go along. Computing $|r(v_i)|$ for each $v_i$ is discussed at e.g. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-bounds-can-be-put-on-counting-reachable-nodes-in-a-dag.   You could use Edith Cohen's linear-time approximation algorithm for that ("Size-Estimation Framework with Applications to Transitive Closure and Reachability"), and _maybe_ (by putting weight-zero on nodes not in $T$?) also estimate ancestors in $T$.

Comment: So computing the number of ancestors of $v_i$ in $T$ as you go along is not quite trivial in near-linear time (I don't know how). Suppose you have a node $v_i$ that you *did not add* to $T$ when you processed it in the topological order of processing. Then, later, you add $v_j$ (when you reach it during your processing) where $j > i$ to $T$. Suppose $v_i$ is an ancestor of $v_j$. When you add $v_j$, you also add $v_i$ by the problem definition. Then, how do you obtain the right set of ancestors in $T$ for every node later in the processing order? How does one account for $v_i$ is now in $T$?

Comment: Oh I missed the part about adding $v_i$'s ancestors as well.  And I agree it seems challenging, either way.